# Products of $k^{\mu(k)}$, where $\mu(n)$ is Möbius function, and the Prime Number Theorem

Tags: limits, summation, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

We can write $$e^{-\Lambda(n)}=\prod_{d\mid n}d^{\mu(d)},$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the **Möbius function** and thus $\Lambda(n)$ is **von Mangoldt's function**. Then taking the product from $1$ to $N$ we've for the **second Chebyshev's function** $\psi(x)$ that
$$e^{-N\psi(N)}= \prod_{n=1}^{N} \prod_{d\mid n} d^{\mu(d)},$$
and the **Prime Number Theorem** states that 
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left(  \prod_{n=1}^{N} \prod_{d\mid n} d^{\mu(d)} \right)^{\frac{1}{N^2}} =\frac{1}{e}.$$

I don't know if previous exercise was in the literature, and when I was looking a comparison with different partial product I wrote the following.

Combining **Abel's identity** $$\prod_{k=1}^Nk^{\mu(k)}=\frac{N^{M(N)}}{e^{\int_{1}^N\frac{M(t)}{t}dt}},$$
where $M(n)$ is the **Mertens function**, and the **Prime Number Theorem** one has $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left( \prod_{k=1}^Nk^{\mu(k)} \right)^{\frac{1}{N}}=\lim_{N\to\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{N}\int_{1}^N\frac{M(t)}{t}dt} $$

> **Question.** Can you justify that the limit exists and is $1$, I ask $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left( \prod_{k=1}^Nk^{\mu(k)} \right)^{\frac{1}{N}}=1?$$
>   **Thanks in advance.**

I don't know if it is right. I know that the order of magnitude of the Mertens function is an unsolved problem, but are known good bounds. In the other I don't know if my questions is, perhaps an easy problem of analysis, on asumption that [this limit exists](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124308/prod-n-1-infty-n-mun-frac14-pi-2/124324#124324). Truly I don't understand nothing of this post from MathOverflow, I say that I don't know after read it (my english is bad and there is a discussion) if the limit $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{\mu(k)}$ there exists (?), and take the cited value (also I don't know if such unsolved problem involving the Mertens function, is an additional problem when I read the partial product of this last infinite product as the ratio that I wrote, if you know/want clarify to me these doubts you can add comments about this).

Comment: In the last paragraph (it isn't neccesary that you answer this question to solve the post, but I will apprecitate it) I am asking if in the computation of the limit $\prod_{k=1}^Nk^{\mu(k)}=\frac{N^{M(N)}}{e^{\int_{1}^N\frac{M(t)}{t}dt}}$ as $N\to\infty$ you need know the right magnitude order of the Mertens function, or you can compute the limit $N\to\infty$ of LHS without this knowledge.

Comment: why are you obfuscating the things with products ? it seems useless. so  $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = -\sum_n \Lambda(n) n^{-s}$ and $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_n \mu(n) n^{-s}$ and $\zeta'(s) = -\sum_n \ln(n) n^{-s}$ hence $\Lambda(n) = \sum_{d |n } \mu(d) \ln(n/d) = \ln(n)  \sum_{d |n }\mu(d) -  \sum_{d |n } \mu(d) \ln(d) =  -  \sum_{d |n } \mu(d) \ln(d)$ when $n > 1$.  since $\psi(N) = \sum_{n \le N} \Lambda(N)$ we get $\Psi(N) = -\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{d |n } \mu(d) \ln(d)$ not $N \psi(N)$. and the prime number theorem says that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\psi(N)}{N} = 1$.

Comment: then, $\left(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\right)' = -\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2} = -\sum_n \ln(n) \mu(n) n^{-s}  = -s \int_1^\infty A(x) x^{-s-1} dx$ with $A(N) = \sum_{n \le N} \ln(n) \mu(n)  = \int_{1-\epsilon}^{N+\epsilon} \left(\sum_n \ln(n) \mu(n) \delta(x-n)\right) dx = \int_{1-\epsilon}^{N+\epsilon} \left(\sum_n \mu(n) \delta(x-n)\right) \ln (x) dx $ by integration by part   $A(N) = M(N) \ln N - \int_1^N \frac{M(t)}{t} dt$.

Comment: then $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{A(N)}{N} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{M(N) \ln N}{N} - \frac{1}{N} \int_1^N \int_1^N \frac{M(t)}{t} dt = -\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1}{N} \int_1^N \int_1^N \frac{M(t)}{t} dt$, and for evaluating that limit you have to look the order of the pole of $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)^2$ at $s=1$. it is of order $0$ since $\zeta'(s)$ has a pole of order $2$ and $\zeta(s)^2$ has a zero of order $2$, hence by the PNT  $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)^2$ is holomorphic on $Re(s) = 1$, hence $A(N) = o(N)$, and $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{A(N)}{N} = 0$

Comment: I meant $1/\zeta(s)^2$ has a zero of order $2$ at $s=1$, and $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{M(N) \ln N}{N} = 0$ again by the PNT

Comment: Very thanks much @user1952009 I will try read and understand your very detailed answer, very thanks much. My idea of ​​using products is by similarity and mysticism (I try understand 
possible relationships between sums and products). I understand then that it isn't neccesary use products, since I understand  from your words that my computations can be justify from the theory. To clarify myself, then the **Question** is right? and what's the right answer? Many thanks,

Comment: @user1952009 Why did you write an answer as $4$ comments?

Comment: Yesterday, I wrote the question, and after I was disconnected, since here it was late night.  In the other hand I try understand if the **Question** has mathematical meaning, if it isnt only take the exponential of known identities, and what is the value of the limit. Thanks all users.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini : because there is no question

Comment: @user1952009 I think it may be an answer. And this consideration comes from the fact I have to zoom to read what you wrote :D

Comment: Very thanks much both.